# Gstreamer-sharp, build libgstreamersharpglue.so

Tags: linux, makefile, shared-libraries, gstreamer

I trying to build `libgstreamersharpglue-1.0.0.so` for Linux using [gstreamer-sharp](https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp/tree/master/sources/glue).

I downloaded it and installed using `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr && make install`. After that I went to `/gstreamer-sharp-master/sources/glue/` and tried to build glue using `make`, but it built only `libgstreamersharpglue-1.0.0.la`. So how can I build `libgstreamersharpglue.so`(shared library) with this glue source for Linux? Or how can I get `libgstreamersharpglue.so`?

Comment: did you try to do `make` before `make install` in the root folder?

Comment: @knocte if I do `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr` and after that `make` in the `gstreamer-sharp` dir, then I get `./Playback.cs(31,24): error CS0117: 'Gst.Parse' does not contain a definition for 'Launch'` error in the `gstreamer-sharp/samples` dir. But this error occurs after `Making all in sources/glue`

Comment: that is a different problem: you need glib-sharp master

Comment: @knocte sorry, but what do you mean? And need for what?

Comment: glib-sharp is a dependency of gstreamer-sharp, you need to update your glib-sharp so that gstreamer-sharp can build, I believe

Comment: @knocte I tried to install [gtk-sharp](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp)(which includes glib-sharp) again using `./configure`,`make` and `make install` and after that I tried to build gstreamer-sharp again but this error occurred again.

Comment: @knocte ok, I found solution, you can amend it, if you see fit. Thanks for support!

Comment: glad you got further

Comment: when installing glib-sharp without specifying a prefix, glib-sharp got installed in /usr/local, which later was not seen by gstreamer-sharp because you're installing it in /usr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102390/discussion-between-user2656632-and-knocte).

Comment: @knocte Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102397/room-for-user2656632-and-knocte).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `libgstreamersharpglue-1.0.0.so` should be added in the `/usr/lib` dir after gstreamer-sharp installation automatically, but due to I skipped all buildings after `./Playback.cs(31,24): error CS0117: 'Gst.Parse' does not contain a definition for 'Launch'` it has not been built and added to `/usr/lib`.

**Solution:**

I removed any mentions about `samples` in the `Makefile.am` and `configure.ac`. After that I do `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr && make install`. Now `libgstreamersharpglue-1.0.0.so` exists in the `/usr/lib`.